# Mailer not working

Tags: email, cron-job, scheduling

The automated mailer on CiviCRM does not seem to be working. The scheduled emails are not going out. When I test the system I get the test mail OK but that's about it. Have double checked all obvious settings and manually executed the cron job twice.

Using CiviCRM 4.6 combined with Joomla. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: What happens when you manually execute the cron job?  Are the emails sent?

Comment: (I don't have enough points to comment, so writing here.) I also have this issue. For me it started after the upgrade to Joomla 3.4.6 or 3.4.7 (which came one day later). I hadn't checked between those two upgrades. Using CiviCRM 4.6.10, PHP 5.5 Cron jobs are running correctly; checked by redirecting output and error out and watching time stamps on files. Checking the error_log file (for Joomla) at /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/error_log shows errors like the following: **[24-Dec-2015 05:24:01 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

Comment: This thread on LinkedIn references a change in Joomla release 3.4.7 which changed (hardened security for) session handling. This matches up with the errors I'm seeing. https://www.linkedin.com/groups/52867/52867-6084818608314212353

Comment: Since this question might be about how to add a cron job (not clear to me if that was the correct answer), I've posted a separate question specifically about the Job scheduler failing after Joomla update: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8522/job-scheduler-not-working-after-joomla-update

Comment: This problems was solved to me with the update of Joomla! 3.4.8. The patch specific is: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/8773/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up the appropriate scheduled job?  The one you want is to 'process_mailing'

More details here: [Managing Scheduled Jobs](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs)