# Job scheduler not working after Joomla update

Tags: joomla, mailing, scheduling

The Joomla 3.4.7 update changed the session handler (mentioned in this [LinkedIn posting](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/52867/52867-6084818608314212353) )

The job scheduler fails. Looking at the error log here
**/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/error_log** shows errors like the following:

**[24-Dec-2015 05:24:01 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home//public_html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 448**

I also mentioned this in this [other stackexchange posting](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/mailer-not-working) but I think that posting is considered answered.

Do I need to file a bug report anywhere else?

Comment: It seems session issue. Can you check it in cognito browser? Also clear all the cache.

Comment: This problems was solved to me with the update of Joomla! 3.4.8. The patch specific is: github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/8773/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update to Joomla 3.4.8 fixed the issue with session errors. Scheduled jobs are being called from the running cron job now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if after updating to the latest version of Joomla! and clearing all the cache it still is an issue, please post on https://issues.civicrm.org

Comment: Thanks for the link. After updating to Joomla 3.4.8 (3 updates in 5 days!), it's working again.